# REST API calls not working in swift

Tags: swift, rest

I'm following this tutorial for making a simple REST API call in swift: https://grokswift.com/simple-rest-with-swift/
The problem I'm running into is that the data task completion handler next gets executed. When I'm debugging it step by step, it just jumps over the completion handler block. Nothing is printed in the console, either.
I've searched for other methods of making REST API calls, but they are all very similar to this one and not working, either.

Here is my code:

```
    let endpoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET")
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error receiving data")
            return
        }
        do {
            print ("Parsing response...")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point **inside** the closure? Completion handler is executed when the communication is completed, long after the execution of `task.resume()` in another thread. You cannot step into the completion handler from outside of the closure.

Comment: Yes try putting break point on the first line of your closure. I am able to run your code with results without problem

Comment: I've put breakpoints all over the place inside the closure, and nothing is hit. Also none of the messages inside the closure is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right to me. I tested it in a Playground and I'm getting the `Parsing response...` message printed to the console which makes me think the issue is elsewhere in your code or environment. I'd be happy to take a look at the whole project if you can post a Github link or something similar.

Here are the steps I would take to debug an issue like this:

**1)** Confirm my execution environment has an active internet connection. The Safari app can be used to confirm on iOS devices or the Simulator. Playgrounds can be tested by pasting the following lines.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
print (try? String(contentsOf: url))
```

Look for a line in the console output similar to:

```
Optional("{\n  \"userId\": 1,\n  \"id\": 1,\n  \"title\": \"delectus aut autem\",\n  \"completed\": false\n}")
```

**2)** Confirm the url is valid and returns data by pasting it into a web browser url bar and hitting enter. You will either see JSON printed in the browser or not.

**3)** Confirm my code is actually getting called when the application runs. You can do this with either breakpoints or `print()` statements. As OOPer2 pointed out asynchronous callback closures like that used in `session.dataTask()` execute in a different time than the rest of your code which is why *"it just jumps over the completion handler block"* while stepping through with the debugger. You'll need to put another breakpoint or print() statement inside the completion handler closure. I'd put the breakpoint on the `guard error == nil else {` line.

**4)** Make sure the application is still executing when the network request finishes and the completion handler closure executes. If your code is in a ViewController running in an iOS application it's probably fine, but if it's running in a Playground it may not be. Playgrounds by default stop execution once the last line of code has been evaluated which means the completion closure will never execute. You can tell a Playground to continue executing indefinitely by importing the `PlaygroundSupport` framework and setting `needsIndefiniteExecution = true` on the current Playground page. Paste the entire code block below into a Playground to see it in action:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

// Keep executing the program after the last line has evaluated so the
// closure can execute when the asynchronous network request finishes.
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// Generic Result enum useful for returning values OR an error from
// asynchronous functions.
enum Result<T> {
    case failure(Error)
    case success(T)
}

// Custom Errors to be returned when something goes wrong.
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case couldNotCreateURL(for: String)
    case didNotReceiveData
}

// Perform network request asynchronous returning the result via a
// completion closure called on the main thread.
//
// In really life the result type will not be a String, it will
// probably be an array of custom structs or similar.
func performNetworkRequest(completion: @escaping (Result<String>)->Void ) {
    let endpoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        let error = NetworkError.couldNotCreateURL(for: endpoint)
        completion(Result.failure(error))
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // This closure is still executing on a background thread so
        // don't touch anything related to the UI.
        //
        // Remember to dispatch back to the main thread when calling
        // the completion closure.

        guard error == nil else {
            // Call the completion handler on the main thread.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(Result.failure(error!))
            }
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            // Call the completion handler on the main thread.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(Result.failure(NetworkError.didNotReceiveData))
            }
            return
        }

        // Parse response here...

        // Call the completion handler on the main thread.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(Result.success("Sucessfully parsed results"))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

performNetworkRequest(completion: { result in
    // The generic Result type makes handling the success and error
    // cases really nice by just using a switch statement.
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let parsedResponse):
        print(parsedResponse)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1) I've put these 2 lines outside the closure, and I do see the message printed in the console. However, when I put the lines inside the closure, the message is not printed. 2) Yes, I've done that with the url given in the code, and it does return data. 4) I'm not running the code in a Playground. 3) I think I get it now. The breakpoints were not hit because I stopped debugging after this function returns, as I need to do something with the data immediately afterward. When I let the program run after the function returned, the breakpoints inside the closure are hit.

Comment: Now my question is, since I need to use the data immediately after this function returns, how can I guarantee that I will have the data and have parsed it in the do block when I need to use it?

Comment: Well that's a bigger question with a much bigger answer. You will probably want to spend some time learning about multi-threading before you tackle this (also referred to as concurrency). I highly recommend working through this Ray Wenderlich tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: After that I imagine you will decide you really don't NEED that data immediately when the function returns because that would block the thread you're calling from which is almost certainly the main UI thread. In other words the user interface would freeze until the network request finished.

Comment: I suspect you will decide to add a completion closure to the function which will return the results back to your main thread. This stuff gets a little complicated but it's TOTALLY worth it in the long run. You'll need to learn it sooner or later.

Comment: I've updated the Playground code example to demonstrate the general pattern I use when working with asynchronous code (like network requests). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use this Library **Alamofire is an HTTP networking library written in Swift.**

Add this line to your **Podfile**

```
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
```

Then, run the following command:

```
    pod install
```

Then in your **ViewController** file:

`import Alamofire`

```
Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").responseJSON { response in

     print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
     print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
     print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

     if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
     }

     If let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
       print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
     }
}
```

And in here are an example of how to parse the result.

https://github.com/CristianCardosoA/JSONParser

For more info about Alamofire:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

I hope this help.